# How to serve multiple node apps in a single digitalocean vps server?

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-location

Below given is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file. I have added the two new location blocks with their respective localhost links, only the root one, with localhost 8000 is being server by nginx. The other two links doesn't work.

Example

```
http://111.111.111.111 = Works
http://111.111.111.111/app1 = Doesn't work
http://111.111.111.111/app2 = Doesn't work
http://111.111.111.111:3000 = Doesnt't work
http://111.111.111.111:4000 = Doesnt't work
```

How do I fix the following file so that I can access the three node apps running on three ports(3000, 4000 and 8000). Thanks in advance for any help

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

# root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
#   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Below is mt `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Does the working endpoint take you to the node app serving port 8000?

Comment: Yes, I can access the root location / which is running on port 8000. I am unable to access the other two ports.

Answer (score 3):

For a full configuration, check out my answer to [Configuring Load Balancer to Route to different pages of instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52981514/1199102). You don't need the `root /var/www/html;` as you aren't serving a static html page.

You need the proper forwarding headers:

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

You should also use `127.0.0.1` over `localhost`, and create a block for each upstream node.js server nginx is acting as a reverse-proxy for:

```
upstream root {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  keepalive 256;
}

upstream app1 {
  server 127.0.0.1:4000
  keepalive 256;
}

upstream app2 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000
  keepalive 256;
}

server {
  listen      80 default_server;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://root;
    proxy_pass_header       Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header       X-UA-Compatible;
    proxy_pass_header       Server;
    proxy_buffers 64        16k;
    proxy_buffer_size       16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_read_timeout      10;
    proxy_redirect          off;
  }

  location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://app1;
    proxy_pass_header       Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header       X-UA-Compatible;
    proxy_pass_header       Server;
    proxy_buffers 64        16k;
    proxy_buffer_size       16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_read_timeout      10;
    proxy_redirect          off;
  }

  location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://app2;
    proxy_pass_header       Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header       X-UA-Compatible;
    proxy_pass_header       Server;
    proxy_buffers 64        16k;
    proxy_buffer_size       16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_read_timeout      10;
    proxy_redirect          off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my server code and the code above to reflect the changes you suggested. It still doesn't seem to work. Is there simething that needs to be done inside sites-enabled folder? Or any other folder?

Comment: Ah, you also need the upstream_app definition. I will edit with a full working example. I didn't notice this was missing.

Comment: @HishamMubarak If still having trouble after applying changes, please include your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file

Comment: I have added the nginx.conf along with the question. Can you take a look at it? Thank you